# Basic Pie Chart linked to SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, data, google-chart

I'm trying to link a Google pie chart with a Sharepoint List consisting of two columns, Title and Count (x6ei). I'm getting nothing in the webpart in Sharepoint. Can anyone help?

Here is the .js file I have it linked to:

```
    google.charts.load("current", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});

var ProjectArray = [];
getChartData();

function getChartData() {

    var serverRelativeUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    var columns = "Title,x6ei";
    var listName = "agency_cert_status";
    var orderby = "x6ei asc";
    var restURL = serverRelativeUrl.concat("/_api/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=" + columns + "&$orderby=" + orderby);

    $.ajax({
        url: restURL,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
                
        error: function (error) {}
    })
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(renderChart);
};

function renderChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);
       var options = {
        // This line makes the entire category's tooltip active.
        tooltip: { isHtml: true },
    // Use an HTML Legend.
        legend: { isHtml: true },      
       }
      };    
      
    chart.draw(options);
};
```

Here is the .html file:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://oursite.sharepoint.com/sites/oursite/SitePages/Test/ProjectGraph_2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <div id="myChart"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this all your code? I'm not seeing where you process the results or where you pass them to the chart.

Answer (score 1):

No binding logic of data to chart, you could check my previous test demo [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b44ed444-81ec-48d7-a98a-1323f8816672/error-when-creating-google-charts-in-rest-sharepoint-removing-duplicates-entries?forum=sharepointdevelopment).

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(NumberOfUsersPerRegion );
    //google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(NumberOfUsersPerRegion);
function NumberOfUsersPerRegion () {
    
            var dataCharts = new google.visualization.DataTable();  
            dataCharts.addColumn('string', 'Category');  
            dataCharts.addColumn('string', 'User Count');  

             var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
                     "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('NPT Tickets')/items?$select=Loc,Category,Ticket_x0020_By/Title&$Expand=Ticket_x0020_By/Title";

             // execute AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                                url: requestUri,
                                type: "GET",
                                async:false,
                                headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                                success: function (data) {                                 
                                                console.log(data);
                                                 
                                                var dataResults = data.d.results;
                                                var Regions;
                                                var timelost;
                                                var addTimeLost = 0;
                                                var Users;
                                                
                                               
                                                for (i=0; i< data.d.results.length; i++) {                                    
                                                                
                                                                
                                                                Timelost = dataResults[i].Time_x0020_Lost;
                                                                Location = dataResults[i].Loc;
                                                                Category=dataResults[i].Category;
                                                                Users = dataResults[i].Ticket_x0020_By.Title;
                                                                console.log(Users);
                                                                dataCharts.addRow([Category , Users]); 
                                                                
                                                }
                                                
                                  },
            
                        });
                        console.log(dataCharts);

            
             var newData = google.visualization.data.group(dataCharts, [{
                      column: 0,
                      label: 'Location',
                      type: 'string'
                  }], [{
                      column: 1,
                      label: 'Number of users',
                      aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
                      type: 'number'
                  }]);

                  var options = {'title':'Cummulative Time Lost in All Locations',
                       'width':700,
                       'height':500};
                
              var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('NumberOfUsersPerRegion'));
              console.log(newData);
              chart.draw(newData, options);


             }//end of function NumberOfUsersPerRegion

</script>
```